# Setting GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP cause GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glUseProgram

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, texture-mapping

I am using the following function to load my cube map. Without loading, there is no error. Whenever I set me cube map texture next `glUseProgram()` function causes GL_INVALID_OPERATION error;

```
unsigned int Model::loadCubemap(std::vector<std::string> faces){
    GLuint CubeMapOrder[] = {
            GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X,
            GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y,
            GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z
    };
    unsigned int textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textureID);

    int width, height, nrComponents;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++){
        unsigned char *data = stbi_load(faces[i].c_str(), &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);
        if (data){
            GLenum format;
            if (nrComponents == 1){
                format = GL_RED;
            }else if (nrComponents == 3){
                format = GL_RGB;
            }else if (nrComponents == 4){
                format = GL_RGBA;
            }
            glTexImage2D(CubeMapOrder[i], 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
            stbi_image_free(data);
        }else{
            std::cout << "Cubemap texture failed to load at path: " << faces[i] << std::endl;
            stbi_image_free(data);
        }
    }

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    return textureID;
}
```

I am setting my cube map for cube map shader like this;

```
    GLuint TextureID  = glGetUniformLocation(ShaderProgram::shaders[shadername]->programID, "skybox");
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE8);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, cubemapTexture);
    glUniform1i(TextureID, 8);
```

for the first cube map shader, it works. I see the skybox. but another shader that doesn't use skybox texture gives an error.

Both shaders are using the same vertex array object. But the skybox is texture 8. I think the problem is textures parameters. because

if I don't set these

```
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

there is no problem.

I made some digging and couldn't find my problem.

Why setting glTexParameteri gives an error and there is no render.

I am just setting a parameter for GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP. Even if it is wrong why the other textures are affected?

Comment: Please provide the related shader code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have something like

`uniform samplerCube PointShadowMapTexture[MAX_POINT_LIGHT];`

you have to uniform all elements in samplerCube array. Otherwise, there will be a black screen. Or your clear color.Also following draw calls may cause invalid operation.

Better to uniform all unused sampler types with blank 1x1 textures.